# p12 distribution certificate didn't showup in xcode "team"

Tags: ios, xcode

Before anything else. I did read number of threads here in SO but didn't found solution that can resolve our issue. Most of them is about how to create the distribution certificate.

We have a client and they want there developer account to use use to sign the app to be sent to the App Store. I read here that they can gave us a .p12 distribution certificate which I can then install to our machine.

We were able to successfully installed the .p12 file that they sent and it show up in our Keychain access list. But still in *xcode > targets > general > signing > team* it didn't show the client's team so I can only select our company's team. But if I go to *xcode > targets > build settings > code signing identity > release* I can see the installed .p12 certificate in the list. But when I try to archive the app to produce an .ipa file it causes an error "cannot be registered to your development team..."

Shouldn't the client's team appear in *team's selection* when I installed the .p12 certificate that they sent to use?

EDIT:
Is it possible to sign an app with only .p12 provided?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But still in xcode > targets > general > signing > team it didn't show the client's team

No, for that you’d have to sign into the Accounts preference pane as a member of that team. The client needs to sign you on at the Member Center as a team member so you can do that. That information doesn’t magically derive from the certificate. Indeed, until you are a team member the certificate is useless to you (as you’ve already discovered).

Comment: Thanks! I have the client invite us to there team! It's showing their team now in the list.